# How to resume bits transfer after network issue

Tags: powershell

I'm using asynchronous bits transfer to download a file from a remote server where I'm connected through the VPN.
Is there any way how to continue with downloading after VPN is disconnected?

When I start downloading then suspend my VPN and resume it after few seconds bits transfer fails with TransientError.

```
$transferCredentail = Get-Credential
$transferJob = Start-BitsTransfer -Source "\\remoteserver\path\filename" -Credential $transferCredentail -Destination C:\Temp -Description "Test" -Asynchronous

while (($transferJob.JobState -eq "Transferring") -or ($transferJob.JobState -eq "Connecting"))
{
    Write-Output $transferJob.JobState
    sleep 5;
}

Switch($transferJob.JobState)
{
    "Transferred" {Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $transferJob}
    "Error" {$transferJob | Format-List } # List the errors.
    default 
    {
        Write-Output $transferJob.JobState
        "Other action"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Just check `TransientError` state in while loop. After some time the job state switched back to `Transferring` state and download completed successfully.

```
while (($transferJob.JobState -eq "Transferring") -or ($transferJob.JobState -eq "Connecting") -or ($transferJob.JobState -eq "TransientError"))
{
    Write-Output $transferJob.JobState
    sleep 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your `switch` statement for `suspended` jobs. I forget what state the bitstransfer job goes into when there are network issues (I think it's suspended) but if that doesn't work, you can add it to your `default` condition and add an `if` condition that handles anything other than the `Transferring` state.

```
Switch($transferJob.JobState)
{
    "Transferred" {Complete-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $transferJob}
    "Error" {$transferJob | Format-List } # List the errors.
    "Suspended" {Get-BitsTransfer | Resume-BitsTransfer}
    default 
    {
        Write-Output $transferJob.JobState
        "Other action"
    }
}
```

This will resume all BitsTransfer jobs owned by the current user. If you had a name to the job, you can reference the name.

Comment: Thanks for help. I've solved it a little bit different.

Comment: Does bitstransfer do multicast?